# javascript по нажатию выбрать данные из td и внести в input

Tags: javascript, input, table

Всем доброго времени суток. Ребята, подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать следующую вещь:

Есть таблица:

```
<table id="mytable">
<tr>
<td class="myclass"><input type="text" value="$row_name"></td>
<td class="myclass"><input type="text" value="$row_edit_num"></td>
<td class="myclass1"><input type="text" value=""></td>
<td class="myclass2">3000</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="myclass"><input type="text" value="$row_name"></td>
<td class="myclass"><input type="text" value="$row_edit_num"></td>
<td class="myclass1"><input type="text" value=""></td>
<td class="myclass2">6000</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

есть кнопочка `<button onClick='' type="submit" >submit</button>`
Как в эту кнопочку прописать функцию, желательно, конечно, отдельно, javascript`om, чтобы по ее нажатию:

значения из `<td class="myclass2">` заполнили данные `<td class="myclass1"><input type="text" value=""></td>`

Т.е., если строк 20-100-1000, чтобы автоматом все `<td class="myclass1"><input type="text" value=""></td>` заполнились значением со столбца `<td class="myclass2">`?

Answer (score 2):

Такой пример вам подходит?

```js
const $table = document.querySelector('table tbody');
const $fill = document.querySelector('button');

$fill.addEventListener('click', event => {
  for (const $row of $table.children) {
    const $input = $row.querySelector('.class1 input');
    const $target = $row.querySelector('.class2');
    
    $input.value = $target.textContent.trim();
  }
});
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td class="class1"><input type="text" /></td>
  <td class="class2">200</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="class1"><input type="text" /></td>
  <td class="class2">300</td>
</tr>
</table>

<button>Fill</button>
```

Comment: vihtor, да, подходит. Привязка к button пока все почему-то портит.

Comment: @scanread, в смысле "портит"? Что именно не так?

Comment: vihtor, все хорошо, я ее в форму поместил, и по нажатию на нее перемещает меня на другую страницу (вторая кнопка в форме, на сохранение данных). Вынес за ее пределы, все гуд. Спасибо большое.

Comment: @scanread, так это ей нужно просто добавить атрибут `type`. Чтобы в итоге получилось `<button type="button">Fill</button>`

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById('btn-submit').addEventListener('click', () => {
  for (let tr of document.querySelectorAll('#mytable tr')) {
    let src = tr.querySelector('.myclass2'),
        dst = tr.querySelector('.myclass1 input');
    if (dst)
      dst.value = src ? src.textContent : '';
  }
});
```

```css
button, tr, input { font: 16px sans-serif; }
input { background-color: transparent; }
#mytable { border-collapse: collapse; margin-bottom: 1em; }
#mytable td { width: 80px; border: 1px solid #ccc; }
#mytable td input { width: 100%; border: none; outline-width: 0; }
#mytable .myclass2 { background-color: #f7f7f7; text-align: center; }
#mytable td[class^="not-"] { background-color: #fee; text-align: center; }
```

```html
<table id="mytable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="myclass"><input type="text" value="1"></td>
      <td class="myclass"><input type="text" value="2"></td>
      <td class="myclass1"><input type="text"></td>
      <td class="myclass2">3000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="myclass"><input type="text" value="3"></td>
      <td class="myclass"><input type="text" value="4"></td>
      <td class="myclass1"><input type="text"></td>
      <td class="not-myclass2" title="не тот класс у ячейки источника">1000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="myclass"><input type="text" value="5"></td>
      <td class="myclass"><input type="text" value="6"></td>
      <td class="myclass1"><input type="text"></td>
      <td class="myclass2">6000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="myclass"><input type="text" value="7"></td>
      <td class="myclass"><input type="text" value="8"></td>
      <td class="not-myclass1"><input type="text" title="не тот класс у инпута назначения"></td>
      <td class="myclass2">2000</td>
    </tr>
  <tbody>
</table>
<button id="btn-submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: yar85, спасибо. Но возникли сложности. Получается, у меня на странице есть кнопочка сохранения, <button type="submit" name="savemul">Сохранить</button>, и выходит, что по нажатию по <button id="btn-submit">Submit</button> данные вносятся и сразу сохраняются, и меня перекидывает на другую страницу... можно ли как-то без привязки к button решить вопрос?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема с `<button id="btn-submit">Submit</button>`, что отправляло на другую страницу, была с моей стороны, я ее поместил в форму. Вынес за нее, все работает. Спасибо огромное, ребята! Вопрос решен.